# $X,Y$ are iid standard normal. what $P( Y > 3X)$

Tags: probability, distributions

I know the answer is 1/2 but I am not sure why. I see that there are 4 cases

1. $X >0, Y > 0 $  Unlikely that $Y >3X$ as they are drawn from the same distribution
2. $X <0, Y > 0 $ Since $X < 0, Y > 3X$ all the time
3. $X >0, Y < 0 $ Since $Y < 0$ it wont be greater than $3X$
4. $X <0, Y < 0 $ X will get more negative so $Y > 3X$

so basically it is just $\frac{1}{4}* 0 + \frac{1}{4}* 1 + \frac{1}{4}* 0 + \frac{1}{4}* 1 = 1/2 $

For 1. I am assuming it is unlikely but that doesn't mean it can't happen. So I am curious if my logic here is correct.

Comment: You don't need to know much about these distributions to figure this out: the result holds for any continuous distribution symmetric about $0.$  The standard Normal distribution is symmetric about $0,$ whence $\Pr(Y\gt 3X) = \Pr(-Y\gt 3(-X))=\Pr(Y\lt 3X),$ implying (from the Law of Total Probability) that $\Pr(Y\gt 3X) = (1 - \Pr(Y=3X))/2.$ That equals $1/2$ because $(X,Y)$ is a continuous random variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it’s 1/2, a simple way to solve it is using normal Rv rules, i.e. $P(Y>3X)=P(Y-3X>0)$, and $Z=Y-3X$ is normal RV with mean $0$ and  variance $10$. Since the mean is $0$, independent of the variance, $P(Z>0)$ is $1/2$, since the normal curve is symmetric around $0$.

Your logic is not correct. We can’t say that given the variables are positive, $P(Y>3X)$ is $0$, and vice versa for both negative case.

**Edit** based on request:
$$E[Z]=E[Y-3X]=E[Y]-3E[X]=0$$
$$\operatorname{var}(Z)=\operatorname{var}(Y-3X)=\operatorname{var}(Y)+(-3)^2\operatorname{var}(X)=10$$

Comment: Could you expand on how you got that $Z$ has mean 0 and variance 10?

Comment: @genescuba I've added some explanation.